# Avoid Jtable row limitation of 100 rows

Tags: jtable

I want to display more than 100 rows of data from my database in one stroke. The table was made using Netbean's drag & drop facility, thus the table properties in netbeans does not allow me to increase the number of rows more than 100.

Comment: I have read the post much before I posted this question, however, it does not satisfy my query. In the meantime, I found a simple solution.

Go to properties, select model, change the default values to your desired values.

Comment: It may work this way, but it is always better to use a class that extends AbstractTableModel, in order to feed your JTable with data from the database.